# Safe way to echo wp_trim_words

Tags: theme-development, themes

Is this unsafe to `echo` as following in the theme?

```
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
$trimmed_excerpt = wp_trim_words( $excerpt, 30);
echo $trimmed_excerpt;
```

If yes, please let me know what is the safe way to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: No problem in doing that :-)

Comment: You can also use [wp_trim_excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt)